# MassTransit: Is it possible to register a handler non-generically?

Tags: c#, masstransit

As far as I can understand from MassTransit's documentation and API, this is the only way to register a method message handler:

```
IServiceBus.SubscribeHandler<T>(Action<T> handler)
```

However, I'd like to register handlers using reflection based on attributes, so Ideally I need something like this:

```
IServiceBus.SubscribeHandler(Type messageType, Action<object> handler)
```

Does anything like that exist, or is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit requires the type information "statically" in the call. There's no way around that.

You can however make calls to the `SubscribeHandler<T>` via reflection and pass in the generic's type information. A extension method to do this would work great, and could likely have the exact same signature you're looking for above.

Comment: Well in the end I used the non-generic version of `Instance()`, since I also needed a handle on the container and a few other bits. I used a combination of reflection `MakeGenericType()` With a strongly-typed runtime-compiled lambda using `Expression`.

But your is the correct answer to the original question :-).

Comment: Sweet, glad you are all sorted. And we a lot of `MakeGenericType` in MT. We even have a helper, `FastInvoke` for calling generic methods via reflection.

Comment: @AmirAbiri may you post your solution with `.Instance(..)`?